# CSS Scale and Transform causing overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

In HTML page I am trying to achieve zoom functionality using CSS transform scale property. Inside the HTML page, I am having more div elements and all are placed using absolute position technique. Then I apply the scale property to each div and I was able to see like zoom but all div positions gots collapsed each other. So how to avoid collapse and maintain the gap between each other after applied scaling.

Please suggest me how to stop overlapping and how to calculate left and top position of each element accordingly to scale property.

```js
var zoomScale = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#zoomin").click(function(){
    if(zoomScale >=4 ) return;
    zoomScale = zoomScale +1;
    dispStatus();
    applyZoomIn();
  });

  function applyZoomIn(){
    $(".zoomable").each(function(index){
      var left = $(this).position().left;
      var top = $(this).position().top;
      var newLeft = left*zoomScale +"px";
      var newTop = top*zoomScale +"px";
      $(this).css('transform',' scale('+zoomScale+','+zoomScale+')')
    });
  }

  function dispStatus(){
    $("#displayStatus").text("Current Zoom Scale : "+zoomScale);
  }
  
  dispStatus();
  
});
```

```css
#container{
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
     border:1px solid red;
     position:relative;
     overflow:auto;
}
.zoomable{
  background-color:lightblue;       
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  transform-origin: top left;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="zoomin"> Zoom In</button>
<div id="displayStatus"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="container">
   <div class="zoomable">First Div</div>
   <div class="zoomable" style="left:105px">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o3Lfwgy7/)

Comment: If you can position your elements with CSS3 Flexbox and Grid layouts, browsers will take care of transforming the parent flex/grid item! Or you could have a single point for [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) and same.

Comment: Just addd the `.zoomable` class to the `.container` div instead of the ones inside.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `.zoomable` div into one more parent (called `.inner-container`) and add zoom functionality to it. So that `.container` div will not get zoomed and zoomable div will maintain position.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var zoomScale = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#zoomin").click(function(){
    if(zoomScale >=4 ) return;
    zoomScale = zoomScale +1;
    dispStatus();
    applyZoomIn();
  });

  function applyZoomIn(){
      $(".inner-container").css('transform',' scale('+zoomScale+','+zoomScale+')');
  }

 
  function dispStatus(){
   $("#displayStatus").text("Current Zoom Scale : "+zoomScale);
  }

  dispStatus();

});
```

```css
    
    .zoomable{
      background-color:lightblue;       
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      position:absolute;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
    #container{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    }
    .inner-container{
      transform-origin: top left; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="zoomin"> Zoom In</button>

<div id="displayStatus"></div>
<br/><br/>

<div id="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="zoomable">First Div
    </div>
    <div class="zoomable" style="left:105px">Second Div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/8fwgy3qa/)

Comment: If you do it this way, you have to specify the class name of the container element that has elements with the zoomable class.  It also assumes that everything inside the inner container should be zoomed, which is a vast assumption to make.  This suggestion is very counter-intuitive and *will* lead to maintenance problems.